Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension. | but it is set that way already
I am working on a website based on React and have problems getting onScroll animations to work.
I tried Aos and react-on-scroll before but that is a different story.
I want to realise this scroll based text animation.
The code for it is:
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import ScrollTrigger from "gsap/ScrollTrigger";
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
// REVEAL //
gsap.utils.toArray(st).forEach(function (elem) {
  ScrollTrigger.create({
    trigger: elem,
    start: "top 80%",
    end: "bottom 20%",
    markers: true, 
    onEnter: function () {
      gsap.fromTo(
        elem,
        { y: 100, autoAlpha: 0 },
        {
          duration: 1.25,
          y: 0,
          autoAlpha: 1,
          ease: "back",
          overwrite: "auto"
        }
      );
    },
    onLeave: function () {
      gsap.fromTo(elem, { autoAlpha: 1 }, { autoAlpha: 0, overwrite: "auto" });
    },
    onEnterBack: function () {
      gsap.fromTo(
        elem,
        { y: -100, autoAlpha: 0 },
        {
          duration: 1.25,
          y: 0,
          autoAlpha: 1,
          ease: "back",
          overwrite: "auto"
        }
      );
    },
    onLeaveBack: function () {
      gsap.fromTo(elem, { autoAlpha: 1 }, { autoAlpha: 0, overwrite: "auto" });
    }
  });
});

And when I try to run it locally (yarn run dev), I get this error:
yarn run v1.22.22
$ vite
(node:19753) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
failed to load config from /home/user/Dokumente/iGem/Wiki/bielefeld-cebitec/vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
/home/user/Dokumente/iGem/Wiki/bielefeld-cebitec/node_modules/gsap/ScrollTrigger.js:12
import { Observer, _getTarget, _vertical, _horizontal, _scrollers, _proxies, _getScrollFunc, _getProxyProp, _getVelocityProp } from "./Observer.js";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1178:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1220:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:169:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

But in my package.json it is that way:
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{ts,tsx,md,json,css}\"",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },

I tried using
import { gsap } from "gsap/dist/gsap";
import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/dist/ScrollTrigger";

instead of
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import ScrollTrigger from "gsap/ScrollTrigger";

But that gave me this error:
yarn run v1.22.22
$ vite
failed to load config from /home/user/Dokumente/iGem/Wiki/bielefeld-cebitec/vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
ReferenceError: st is not defined
    at file:///home/user/Dokumente/iGem/Wiki/bielefeld-cebitec/vite.config.js.timestamp-1719757047245-98fc5a3a220d.mjs:28:20
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

And I have no idea how to resolve that one.
Here is the whole package.json
{
  "name": "team-slug",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "CC-BY-4.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{ts,tsx,md,json,css}\"",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.5",
    "@gsap/react": "^2.1.1",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.170",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.21",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "d3": "^7.9.0",
    "gsap": "^3.12.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.10.2",
    "react-collapsed": "^4.1.2",
    "react-d3-library": "^1.0.4",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-pdf": "^9.0.0",
    "react-photo-album": "^2.4.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.23.0",
    "react-select": "^5.8.0",
    "sass": "^1.77.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/aos": "^3.0.7",
    "@types/d3": "^7.4.3",
    "@types/node": "^20.12.10",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.66",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.22",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.2.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.2.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.6",
    "prettier": "^3.2.5",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^5.2.0"
  }
}


Your package.json snippet appears to just show the (unrelated) scripts entry and doesn't include confirmation that "type": "module" is indeed set in that pakage.json.

@adsy woops thanks I added the whole package.json to my question post. It is indeed set to "type": "module"
